# Gray Jedi Order Queston

Tags: star-wars

What really was the Gray Jedi order?  Please tell me.  I want to know what they really where, there code, and some of the Gray jedi.

Comment: How 'bout Wikipedia?

Answer (score 1):

I would say that there is no Gray Jedi Order because of the very being of the Grey Jedi. They are not Jedi, but they are not Sith. They are Jedi who did not agree with the Council and its decisions, and they abandoned the Order, but they did not have an organized structure. Some consider Qui-Gon Jinn to be a Gray Jedi, others also consider Quinlan Vos to be Gray, and many believe that Ahsoka Tano became a Gray Jedi after the Great Jedi Purge because of this exchange:

> Darth Vader: Revenge is not the Jedi way.
>
> Ahsoka Tano: I am no Jedi.

Comment: Correction: Ahsoka became a gray Jedi after leaving the Jedi order, which was before the purge.

Comment: True. Thank you.